# C# LINQ and func

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, func

This is a simplified version of what I am using, just to let you know of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
public Dictionary<int, Func<int>> Magic(Dictionary<int, int> dictionary)
{
    return dictionary
        .Select(v => new
        {
            key = v.Key,
            function = new Func<int>(() => v.Value + 5)   // *
        })
        .ToDictionary(v => v.key, v => v.function);
}
```

Is it possible to make the line marked with (*) shorter? Because when I try to remove redundant (in my opinion) delegate creation, it is giving errors:

```
function = () => v.Value + 5   // *
```

But it shouldn't give errors, it is clear what the returned type is...

Comment: On an unrelated note, there will probably be less magic in that code than the method name suggests. If your intention with that code is to later change the value in the dictionary and have that change appear in the output of your new dictionary, you will probably be disappointed. (Unless that's the actual magic you want to achieve.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shorten the whole thing to this:

```
public Dictionary<int, Func<int>> Magic(Dictionary<int, int> dictionary)
{
    return dictionary
        .ToDictionary(v => v.Key, v => (Func<int>)(() => v.Value + 5));
}
```

But you still need to explicitly cast to `Func<int>`.

The only other way is this:

```
public Dictionary<int, Func<int>> Magic(Dictionary<int, int> dictionary)
{
    return dictionary
        .ToDictionary<KeyValuePair<int, int>, int, Func<int>>(
            v => v.Key, 
            v => () => v.Value + 5);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Lambda expressions are typeless. That's why you have to add compiler some information to determine it's type (by giving them some context).

> **Note that lambda expressions in themselves do not have a type because the common type system has no intrinsic concept of "lambda expression."** However, it is sometimes convenient to speak informally of the "type" of a lambda expression. In these cases the type refers to the delegate type or Expression type to which the lambda expression is converted.
>
> from [Lambda Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

You can either do it by the type of variable/parameter/property/field you're assigning it to:

```
Func<int> func = () => 5;
```

or by casting it to a delegate:

```
var func = (Func<int>)(() => 5);
```

It's necessary because you can imagine having your own delegate declared as

```
public delegate int MyDelegate();
```

How would the compiler know if your anonymous type property should be typed as `MyDelegate` or `Func<int>`?

Comment: Thanks!! If I understand correctly - you are making another field separate from the query, right? Because it won't work in the line (*)... And I want to make it dependent from v.Value, so it is not constant :)

Comment: Yes, the field solution is not really suitable for anonymous types.